# Split cell content by "';" using VBA or Excel formula

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am new to VBA, so I have trouble writing code in VBA. My problem is writing a code or an Excel formula to extract (for later use) the identifiers that are written in the same cell, split by ";".

For example, this is what I have on a cell:
A11;B22;C33

I need to select A11, B22, C33, as they were written for example, on a column, as different cells, so I can later use them in other formulas.
I don't want to split the content into different columns, I just want to be able to use A11 or B11 furthermore, without editing it in the databse

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow: Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question to include the code, expected behaviour, and what is wrong... then we can try to help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [split text to columns in excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47554289/split-text-to-columns-in-excel)

Comment: I Downvoted/voted to close because you didn't include a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/) , it looks like [no attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/), and it looks like [no research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) was done.

Comment: My idea was to try it with arrays, but I didn't find any tutorials on youtube specifically for that, so I have no ideas left of how to deal with it

Comment: [Split](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/split.php) function was built for this problem

Comment: @AncaVulc: have you looked at [MSDN: Text to Columns](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/split-text-into-different-columns-with-the-convert-text-to-columns-wizard-30b14928-5550-41f5-97ca-7a3e9c363ed7) or as Vegard says, [MSDN: VBA Split Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/split-function)

Comment: @AncaVulc: your answer is also in the [duplicate question I highlight earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15792642/how-to-split-data-in-a-column-into-two-separate-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Split function and pass delimiter (;in your case)

for Example:

```
Var arrayResult = Split("A11;B22;C33",";")
```

you can also use text to column utility in excel.

select the text you want to separate

- go to DATA >
- select text to column>
- select delimited option click Next>
- select your favorite delimiter ;
- click next

you will get the separate values.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following should work as you expect it to, simply amend the worksheet you are using, the cell you are referring to and the Column you wish your results to be placed in:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set the worksheet you are working with
Dim newvar As Variant, var As String
var = ws.Range("A1").Value
'get the contents of your desired cell, in this case A1
newvar = Split(var, ";") 'split the cell contents by delimiter ; into an array

For i = LBound(newvar) To UBound(newvar) 'loop through array to place values into column B
    ws.Cells(i + 1, "B").Value = newvar(i)
Next i
End Sub
```